# Ubuntu just-in-time debugging

Tags: debugging, ubuntu, segmentation-fault

Good Morning everyone

I'm currently facing a segfault at random on a little piece of software, however, It appears only when not started with an attached debugger (due to a possible memory error, where values are initialized in a safe interval when started with a debugger).

Is it possible to attach an debugger only in case of an segfault, just-in-time, like, for example attaching Visual Studio to a process when unhanded exceptions happen in Windows?

I am working on Ubuntu, 32 bit.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box, Ubuntu limits the core file size to "none". Changing it with `ulimit -c unlimited` will allow your errant program to dump core like it should and then GDB will be happy to allow post-mortem analysis of the fault.